# Completion of integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral domain with the $I$-adic filtration. Let $B$ be the fraction field of $A$. My question is the following:

> Is the fraction field of the completion of $A$ the same as the completion of $B$?

Comment: What does fraction field completion of $K$ mean?

Comment: I interpreted your question as being whether or not taking fraction fields commutes with $I$-adic completion. Please edit if your question is in fact something different (note also that the question does not make sense unless $\widehat{A}^I$ is a domain, i.e. $I$ is analytically irreducible)

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38152/do-localization-and-completion-commute and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64399/does-completion-commute-with-localization