Equality of two completions
I have the following question.
Suppose $R$ is Noetherian ring, $I$ is ideal in $R$ and $S$ is multiplicatively closed set. Let $(I^n\colon\langle S\rangle) = \varphi^{-1}(I^nS^{-1}R),$ where $\varphi\colon R\rightarrow S^{-1}R$. Is it true that completion of $R$ with respect to topology given by $\{(I^n\colon\langle S\rangle)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is the same as completion of $S^{-1}R$ with respect to $IS^{-1}R$-adic topology?
Is the question above true if $R$ has additional properties, for example if $R$ is excellent ring or even if $R$ is excellent integral domain? And what if $S$ such a multiplicatively closed set that $R\hookrightarrow S^{-1}R$ (if we don’t require $R$ to be integral domain)?
If those completions are not the same, what are the difference and connection between them? Is the second completion localization of the first completion by $S$?
Is it true that localization by $S$ of the first completion is dense in the second one?
Any help would be appreciated!

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38152 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/64399 might answer your first question.
